# Order records by timestamp, but with specified ID listed first

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

MySQL

```
+----+------------+
| id | timestamp  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 1306922400 |
+----+------------+
| 2  | 1306926000 |
+----+------------+
| 3  | 1306929600 |
+----+------------+
```

PHP

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY ?? DESC, `timestamp` DESC");
```

Order by:

1. Start where `id` is equal to `2`
2. Then order by `timestamp`

Order should be: 2, 3, 1

Comment: LOL first time I see every answers downvoted. This is sparta!

Comment: So many downvotes without any criticism, is there **no** solution?  That's a valid answer, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, meant "no solution/not possible" is a valid answer, if someone were to post it.

Comment: What do you mean "not possible"? lol

Comment: It's indeed possible and I saw at least 3 correct answers here. Is it a new downvoting competition ?

Comment: @a1ex07: lol dunno what's happening xD. I would say let's wait for the krysis choice. Because there are a lot of correct answer there

Answer (score 1):

you could use UNION... But I would avoid it.

```
$a = mysql_query("
                  (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = 2 ) UNION 
                  (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
                ");
```

Considering i didn't an UNION ALL in the second query the record with id = 2 will get not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where id = 2
union 
SELECT * FROM `table` where id != 2 order by id, timestamp desc
```

Comment: any reasons to copy/paste my answer? ^_^

Comment: @yes123 Jody's answer is not identical to yours.

Comment: cause we submitted at the same time =-\

Comment: they might have been typing it while you were clicking submit...only 18 seconds difference.  my $0.02

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id`!=2 ASC,  `timestamp` DESC
// or
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id`=2 DESC,  `timestamp` DESC
```

Comment: Why -1? It returns what you want.

Comment: Does it say syntax error? `timestamp` should be in backticks. I'm updating the answer

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but: "Order should be: 2, 3, 1"

Comment: @Frank Farmer : I agree, it's not clear. But the question also has `ORDER BY timestamp`, so I assumed that all records except with id =2 are sorted properly. But it's also possible that expecting order is `id=2`, then `id DESC`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = 2 ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC UNION SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id != 2 ORDER BY `timestamp DESC");
```